# Best model for client software encryption / decryption

Tags: encryption, rsa, aes, certificates

I would like to develop a small solution (in C#) that must secure data exchange with an untrusted server.

The model is that this software will run on a Windows client then encrypt data before pushing it to the server and then decrypt data when query back from server. Encryption and decryption will happen locally on the client (inside the software C# code). In other words, we want to protect the data against the server in this scenario, and not against clients because they are knowing these data and could be share between them.

For the moment, I have considered to use a Certificate issued by my organization and deployed to each client computer. Then, from my small software, I will use this certificate public key to encrypt and private key for decrypt, by using RSA algorithm.

Should I consider to set this certificate as private key non- exportable, in order to secure it? That's works well but I feel that it's maybe not the right way of using asymmetric encryption in my scenario...

So my questions are:

1. Is it necessary to use asymmetric RSA in my scenario, since the public and private key are known from the client... ? Is it perhaps better to use symmetric encryption with AES and a single key ?
2. Can I fully trust to the fact of setting certificate private key as non exportable ? Is it means that my client user would be really not able to export this key ? I guess no since my program is able to do it :)

Finally, what could you advice to me in order to satisfy this specification by keeping in mind that we want to protect the data pushed to the non trusted server?

Comment: Why do you fear that user can export their private keys, No right to export? You may consider physical tokens to store them. You are confusings the concepts, look at hybrid encryption and see the solution from libsodium.

Comment: Are the clients supposed to be allowed to securely share data among each other or just with themselves (i.e. client A is the only decryptor for client A's data)?

Comment: In fact, I think that AES will be enought for my scenario, since I dont have to exchange data between two distant actors, but finaly with "myself" (the user). 
So the main goal is to protect the data at rest on the distant server and my main fear is that, even if the user can read the data, I want to avoid them knowing the passphrase and prevent a bad intention of a user that could give the pass to the server. So how can I protect the passphrase on a AES scenario ? Exactly as a Private Key is protected in the certificate when using RSA.

Comment: @kelalaka thanks for this idea. It's a good option that I will explore

Comment: @SEJPM No, all users can see all data. Again, I still want to protect the data at rest on the distant server. Can you please consider my comment about AES and protect the passphrase...